# Remove JCombobox border inside JTable

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, tablecelleditor, nimbus

I have removed the arrow button from the `JComoboBox` to make it look like a `JTextField` and added it as a celleditor. The purpose is it create an AutoSuggest(not AutoComplete) JTable cell.

On Doing that the border kinda looks irking.How to change the border to make it look like textfield border on the right. I have tried removing the border created line border. But its not removing the blueish border.

Using Nimbus UI.

[image]

MCVE for the problem

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Sample extends JFrame {

    public Sample() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
        DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new EditorCombo());
        cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(2);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0)
                .setCellEditor(cellEditor);
        table.setRowHeight(30);
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setUpUI("Nimbus");
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Sample samp = new Sample();
                samp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                samp.setTitle("Table Test");
                samp.pack();
                samp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                samp.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void setUpUI(String ui) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if (ui.equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Sample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    class EditorCombo extends JComboBox {

        public EditorCombo() {
            setEditable(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                addItem("Sample" + i);
            }
            setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthComboBoxUI() {
                @Override
                protected JButton createArrowButton() {
                    JButton button = new JButton() {
                        @Override
                        public int getWidth() {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    };
                    button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                    button.setVisible(false);
                    return button;
                }

                @Override
                public void configureArrowButton() {
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using Nimbus UI

Maybe this will help you: [Nimbus Defaults (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Modifying the Look and Feel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html)

- `TextField[Focused].borderPainter`
- `TextField[Enabled].borderPainter`
- `ComboBox:\"ComboBox.textField\"[Enabled].backgroundPainter`
- `ComboBox:\"ComboBox.textField\"[Selected].backgroundPainter`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Sample2 extends JFrame {
  public Sample2() {
    init();
  }

  private void init() {
    JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
    DefaultCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new EditorCombo());
    cellEditor.setClickCountToStart(2);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(cellEditor);
    table.setRowHeight(30);
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    add(new JScrollPane(table));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    setUpUI("Nimbus");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        Sample2 samp = new Sample2();
        samp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        samp.setTitle("Table Test");
        samp.pack();
        samp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        samp.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  private static void setUpUI(String ui) {
    try {
      for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        if (ui.equals(info.getName())) {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
             | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Sample2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}

class EditorCombo extends JComboBox<String> {
  public EditorCombo() {
    super();
    setEditable(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      addItem("Sample" + i);
    }
  }
  @Override public void updateUI() {
    //super.updateUI();
    setUI(new javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthComboBoxUI() {
      @Override
      protected JButton createArrowButton() {
        JButton button = new JButton() {
          @Override
          public int getWidth() {
            return 0;
          }
        };
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setVisible(false);
        return button;
      }
      @Override
      public void configureArrowButton() {
      }
    });
    UIDefaults d = new UIDefaults();
//     putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
//     putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
//     JComponent c = (JComponent) getEditor().getEditorComponent();
//     c.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
//     c.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
//     c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    Painter<JComponent> emptyPainter = new Painter<JComponent>() {
      @Override public void paint(Graphics2D g, JComponent c, int w, int h) {
        /* Empty painter */
      }
    };
    d.put("TextField.borderPainter", emptyPainter);
    d.put("TextField[Enabled].borderPainter", emptyPainter);
    d.put("TextField[Focused].borderPainter", emptyPainter);
    d.put("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.textField\"[Enabled].backgroundPainter", emptyPainter);
    d.put("ComboBox:\"ComboBox.textField\"[Selected].backgroundPainter", emptyPainter);
    d.put("ComboBox[Editable+Focused].backgroundPainter", emptyPainter);
    putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
    JComponent c = (JComponent) getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    c.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", d);
    c.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
  }
}
```